# refresh data using scriptblock vb.net

Tags: vb.net, highcharts

i want to resfresh my data in vb.net

i have my chart in javascript and getting data from the server

the code i have so far:

```
  Dim script As String
         script = _


       "   var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();" & _
        "chart.series[0].setData(array2); " & _
    " }); " & _

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock( _
       Me, _
        GetType(Page), _
       "ToggleScript", _
        script, _
       True)
```

its not working atm, as am not sure whats rong, any idea hows it suppose to be layed out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what you need:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
 string someScript = "<script language='javascript'>container_highcharts();</script>";
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", someScript);
 }
```